# How to Array conversion or transformation in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on php arrays.

Here is my code sample. i'm try this way.

```
    $permit;

    foreach ($request->permission as $key => $value) {
      $permit[]=[
        $key => $value=='true' ? true : false,

      ];
    }
    return ($permit);
```

This show the array list like this.

```
[{
  read: true
}, {
  create: true
}, {
  delete: false
}, {
  update: true
}]
```

But I want to this array list like as.

```
{
  read: true,
  create: true,
  delete: false,
  update: false
}
```

Comment: Put `$key` inside the brackets of `$permit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change this part:

```
$permit[$key] = ($value == 'true');
```

You can further shorten this way... Thanks to [deceze ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze).

Comment: While you're at it you can shorten the right hand side to `$value == 'true'` as well.

Comment: @deceze Ha! True that! That's clever! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

array_map should do the same, bit shorter.

```
$arrayBool = array_map(function($a){return $a == 'true';}, $arrayString);
```